# The greedy regex (robbers)

Tags: string, code-challenge, cops-and-robbers, regular-expression

*This is the robbers' post. The cops' is [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/140863/58826).*

Your challenge is to take a cop's post and find an input that the regex matches but the program returns a falsey value.

Once you have cracked a cop's post, comment in a link to your crack. (If you don't have enough rep to comment, please say so, and someone will do it for you.) The robber with the most cracks wins.

### Example

Let's say a cop's regex is (all of the flavors):

```
/^[0-9]$/
```

And the program is (JS):

```
x=>Boolean(parseInt(x))
```

Than a valid crack would be `0`, because the regex matches `0` but `0` is falsey.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3, pperry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140865/70424)

```
İ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P03BViEnMTcpJVEh0SonNU8jUS8nvzy1SENTU8HWVsGQq6AoM69EI01D6cgGJU3N//8B)

The lower case variant `i̇` of this character is created by a an `i` and a ċȯṁḃi̇̇ṅi̇̇ṅġ ḋȯṫ which results in a length of 2.

Comment: That was the intended solution!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), [ppperry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140870/73819)

```
\n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYoxDoAgDAB3X1EnIDEMfsAf@AITQwwGBlpSuvD6GpXtcne1SyJcVW@mAlQjByGGXCqxAJKcOpjjAq23qXLGv1hzoHFDcPQlyJUsG7vN3pkFvgy5vTPshFH1AQ)

`.` doesn't match newline by default.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript, ThePirateBay](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140895/73026)

Solution:

[Try it online!](https://jsfiddle.net/36x66tck/)

Answer (score 0):

## Java, [Roman Gräf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/140863/the-greedy-regex-cops#140912)

```
is.is.is.is.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHBTsMwDD23X2FVHNJNy4kLmxAHxA0QYojLNqSs80pGmlSJOzamfvto2jAYMCmSFfu952d7JdZiYErUq8XbxV4WpbEEqybJK5KK90bxz5wSOucWlwoz8rW4rOZKZpAp4RzcCalhF0ch6UhQE9ZGLqBoSmxMVup8MgNhc5d6ZDTOhNZowYV4CRrfIWTZeOsICy51OvLYlg5kntBRgwwcrnFDt1Ij61Adx1TEywZPSrPkwZrcimIICfRBuvB9FkouWCeXnuQ@Yo6bIUDgtt8/zDr@PfXcGIVCHzPCBDr1o1ukymrQvBCUvaJj1gM7tWh/Uu7I/EGwXSbZrQ/Rtb8GXxp7Lwpk3fJqyHwbdrPJsCRpNGDr4svGUiiHLfDbGtkK/x0utG0NN4dIXtiVdCmbiMHHrD@d8nR3XvPeWTLaR3G9l44f3ic)

Most things which match the regex crack it, so I'm not sure if the regex is what was intended

Comment: I think the cop misunderstood the challenge, and that you misunderstood the regex : you're right that getting a false from the program while having the regex match is trivial, even more so than you think since `(?is)` is java's shorthand flag notation and turns on case-insensitivity and single-line mode for the rest of the regex, rather than the positive lookahead which it looks like you understood it as. ([little illustration](https://ideone.com/1YAH86))

Comment: @Aaron I've used those flags before so I really should have noticed that. If you would like to post an answer assuming the cop had true and false switches I encourage it since you spotted the intended answer