# The greedy regex (cops)

Tags: code-golf, string, cops-and-robbers, regular-expression, obfuscation

*This is the cops' post. The robbers' is [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/140862/58826).*

You make a program and a regex.

For most inputs, one of the following happens:

- the regex doesn't match, and the program returns a falsey value
- the regex doesn't match, and the program returns a truthy value
- the regex matches, and the program returns a truthy value

But for one (or more) input, the regex matches, but the program returns a falsy value.

You should try to keep this input hidden. Robbers will try to find an input where the regex matches, but the program returns a falsy value.

Post your program and your regex, as well as your language name, byte count of the program, regex flavor, and byte count of the regex.

If a robber finds an input where the regex matches, but the program returns a falsy value, even if it wasn't the intended input your program is considered cracked, and you edit in a link to the robber's crack.

If nobody has cracked your program & regex after a week, then edit in that your submission is safe and is therefore not eligible for cracking. Also edit in the intended input. The shortest (program bytes + regex bytes) non-cracked submission wins.

### Example

Let's say your regex is (all of the flavors):

```
/^[0-9]$/
```

And your program is (JS):

```
x=>Boolean(parseInt(x))
```

Then a valid crack would be `0`, because the regex matches `0` but `0` is falsey.

Delimiters don't count in the byte count.

**I can't enforce the banning of hash functions with rules, but please don't use SHA/RSA or anything that is unfair to the robbers**

Comment: Are cryptographic hash functions allowed? I can imagine regex `(..)+` and program `print hash(input)==...`

Answer (score 2):

## Python, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/140862/the-greedy-regex-robbers/141006#141006)

Regex: `(?!.)`

Program: `from operator import not_`

This is a little easier than my previous one.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140900/72349))

Regex: `..`
Program: `a=>[...a].length-1`

This is an easy one.

---

**Intended solution**

> 

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140900/73026)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, 12 bytes + 3 bytes

Regex: `...`

Code: `a=>a+1<a-1+2`

Comment: It is supposed to be hard to produce a `false`. With your program, almost any 3-digits number (and more inputs) would produce it.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, cracked by ovs

Regex: `.`

Program: `lambda a:len(a.lower()) == 1`

This <s>shouldn't be</s> wasn't too hard.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140891/64121)

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth

Regex: `.*`

Program: `!qC%.hz^TT"U|(¡`

[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%21qC%25.hz%5ETT%22U%7C%28%C2%A1&debug=0)

Simple hash function, shouldn't be allowed, but it is. I could've made it much stronger, but I tried to optimize for byte count.

Comment: Stop suggesting we make things into pop-cons! Pop-cons are almost never good nowadays, and this challenge is much much better as a cops and robbers. The issue is that the OP hasn't yet clarified, which does not mean that it should be a pop-con.

Comment: He has to do one of the two things, otherwise the winner is whoever can create the shortest hash that remains secure.

Comment: I'm not arguing with that, I'm arguing with the *Maybe make the challenge a popularity contest instead*. That is in no way the correct solution to a problem in a question. Take a look through [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) and see how many are closed. Pop-con is not a solution to an under specified challenge, it is a separate challenge type.

Comment: Good point, turns out I wasn't aware of what makes a challenge a good popularity contest. Edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 9)](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/), 198 bytes, ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/140862/the-greedy-regex-robbers/140914#140914))

```java
public static boolean isProgramValid(String n) {
    try{
        Class.forName(n);
    } catch(Exception e){
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static String regex = "^(?is)([a-z]+\\.){4}.*$";
```

Should be an easy one.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVFNT8JAED23v2LSeNhC2JMXIcaDIdFECQH0IpgsZaiL291md4og6W@v/fIDldNkZt6beW9mI7aiZ1LUm9XrRSGT1FiCTVnkGUnFOwP/Z00JHXOLa4URVT0/zZZKRhAp4RzcC6nh4Htt0ZGgMmyNXEFSttiUrNTx0wKEjV1YIb1pJLRGC66Nl6DxDdoqm@4dYcKlDgcVtqYDmRk6KpEth2vc0Z3UyBpUwzEZ8bTEk9IsGFsTW5H0IYAuSNemj0LJFWvGhSe5E4xx1wdouXX6h5n7v10vjVEo9DGjdaDDyrpFyqwGzRNB0Qs6ZitgM80rTo47Ev81sD4m2X0VvOvqG3xt7EgkyJrj5RBVa9hwF2FK0mjAWsWnjLVQDmvgtzSyGf5rrl1bCy4fETyzK@lC9iR674vufM7Dw3nOO2fBoPD8vDjcjsYPM7gZTob5Bw)

Comment: Isn't the question tagged as `code-golf`? Why all these white spaces and boolean instead of int?

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/140862/the-greedy-regex-robbers/140914#140914)